# Can I use google map to develop my own GPS mobile app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mobile-application

I am developing a android app, main feature of the app is GPS navigation for driving and cycling. I am using google map api v3. Is that legal to do this.

Thanks In advance,
Praveen.

Comment: Did you try reading the license agreement available from Google themselves? _And why not?_
(Also, this is only very vaguely a programming related question, next time please read the [FAQ] about what to post, and what not.)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), chapter 10.4 (c)(iii):

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.